# How to generate swagger documentation from nginx conf file?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

I need to get a list of endpoints, that are currently available on nginx plus. Live or list view before running nginx. However I couldn't find any solution.
Is it even possible and if so, with some tool, that can be implemented in k8s, helm.. so its automated?

The endpoint would be of course admin access only.

Example:

```
location = /nginx {

  limit_except OPTIONS GET {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: [This](https://demo.nginx.com/swagger-ui/nginx_api.yaml) looks like the swagger configuration you are looking for.

Comment: @ponsfrilus Well not precisely. This is openApi for REST Api already built in nginx. I'm looking for generating openApi from my own nginx.conf file.